# def __init__( IndentationError: unexpected indent, browser automate selenium OOP

Tags: python, selenium, oop, web-scraping

I am having this indentation error in the def **init**. My goal is to configure the browser for a web scraping app.

this is the code for the config part:

```
CHROMEDRIVER_PATH = r"C:\Users\Narsil\dev\seleniumDrivers\chromedriver.exe"

class Browser_bot(webdriver.Chrome):
  """ 
  Class to manage and configure web browser 
 """
    def __init__(
            self, driver_path=CHROMEDRIVER_PATH, headless=True, time_out=0, 
            proxy_server="", proxy_port="", proxy_user="", proxy_pass="", 
            chrome_folder="", user_agent=True, capabilities=False):
        
        """
        Constructor of the class
        """
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a space before your first coment (Line 4)

Comment: This should be a comment. Questions caused by typos should be closed, not answered.

Comment: That's a docstring, not a comment. Also, there are two spaces there, and those spaces are not the cause of the bug. In fact, removing them would be even wronger than the current version of the code. The problem isn't that the docstring is indented. The problem is that it's not indented consistently with the rest of the class body.